# Dots won't draw in CGContext in swift MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I've a problem. My dots (GCRect) won't draw on my CGImage. The coordinates are right though.

Here is my code

```
  public func drawFaceDots (onImage image : CGImage) -> CGImage {
    let faceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.width, height: image.height)
    let diameter : CGFloat = 5

    print(faceRect)
    let context = CGContext(data:  nil, width: image.width, height: image.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * image.width, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)!

    //context.draw(image, in: faceRect)
    context.setFillColor(NSColor.red.cgColor)

    for point in self.orignalFace! {
        print("Point(\(point.x);\(point.y))")
        let widthX = point.x * CGFloat(image.width) + diameter
        let heightY = point.y * CGFloat(image.height) + diameter
        let boundingRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(image.width) * point.x, y: CGFloat(image.height) * point.y, width: widthX, height: heightY)

        print("BoundingRect : \(boundingRect))")

        context.addEllipse(in: boundingRect)
        context.setFillColor(NSColor.green.cgColor)

    }

    return context.makeImage()!

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a bezier path but you never request it to be drawn.

add:

```
context.fillPath()
```

or alternatively:

```
context.drawPath(using: .fill)
```

after the loop.